# iptables whitelist doesn't work while blacklist does

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

Allowing forwarding for all and blocking a set of ips work:

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set denied_ips src,dst -j REJECT
```

But denying forwarding for all and allowing a set of ips doesn't work:

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set allowed_ips src,dst -j ACCEPT
```

What's up with this?

edit: For clarification here are my rules. I want `FORWARD` to drop everything not in `allowed_ips`.

```
#iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m set --match-set allowed_ips src,dst -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: try removing dst. What command did you use to create the sets?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
It turns out

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set allowed_ips src,dst -j ACCEPT
```

matches only when both src **AND** dst in `allowed_ips`. I mistakenly thought it would match when either src or dst are in `allowed_ips`.